# Git push with full refspec not working

Tags: git, github, push, refspec

I have 2 branches (both locally and remotely on github). I will call them BranchA and BranchB.
I have BranchA with commits c1, c2 and c3.
I have BranchB only with commit c1.
Both branches are totally updated with github, and I can check that BranchA has c1,c2 and c3 and BranchB has only c1.

I want to push from local BranchA to remote BranchB. To do this I try:

```
git push origin refs/heads/BranchA:refs/remotes/origin/BranchB
```

When I do this, I get a strange output:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
   <hash>  BranchA -> origin/BranchB
```

When I go to github I see that BranchB is not updated and still only has c1.
Then, if I run the command again, it returns that everything is up to date.

This was confusing me, but it got worse since when I try to do the command **without** the full ref, like this:

```
git push origin BranchA:BranchB
```

...it worked.

I am very confused by this. I searched for it and I thought that using the full ref (*/refs/heads/* for example) would never do any harm.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it work when I specify the full branch name?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use the full ref spec?

Comment: remote full ref spec for the BranchB in the command will be refs/heads/BranchB.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It was for no reason in particular, I just thought that for starters I would like to try this with the "less likely to fail" by setting the full path. I was wrong :)

Comment: @prahladvenkata Yes, that seemes to be the case. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [prahlad venkata commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422135/git-push-with-full-refspec-not-working#comment83836948_48422135), the reference on the remote is `refs/heads/BranchB`, not `refs/heads/remotes/BranchB`.

Remember that when using `git push` or its counterpart, `git fetch`, there are *two* Gits, and two repositories, involved in the process.  Let's call these yours (matovski's) and GitHub's.

Your Git has a branch named `BranchA` whose full name is `refs/heads/BranchA`.  This name stores a (single) hash ID.

Their Git has a branch named `BranchB` whose full name is `refs/heads/BranchB`.  Their Git probably also has a branch named `BranchA`.  These names also store hash IDs (one each).

When your Git talks to GitHub's Git, your Git sees their `refs/heads/BranchA` and their `refs/heads/BranchB`.  Your Git would like to remember those two name-and-ID pairs, but if your Git stored them as `refs/heads/BranchA` and `refs/heads/BranchB`, your Git would *overwrite* your own branches.  So your Git renames their branch names, replacing `refs/heads/` with `refs/remotes/origin/`.

In other words, `refs/remotes/origin/BranchB` is *your* Git's memory of *their* Git's `refs/heads/BranchB`.  But when your Git talks to their Git, your Git has to tell their Git:*Please set your `refs/heads/BranchB`*.  If your Git asks their Git to set their `refs/heads/origin/BranchB`, that would set their Git's memory of some third Git's `refs/heads/BranchB` (which, as you just saw, is sometimes allowed!—it just has no useful effect in this case, since GitHub's Git repos don't use these on their own).

When you use the short-hand syntax `git push origin BranchA:BranchB`, your Git sends their Git a request to set `BranchB`.  Their Git figures out, based on this request, that you probably meant to set their `refs/heads/BranchB`, and does what (it thinks) you meant, rather than what you asked.  This particular trick works only when they already have a `refs/heads/BranchB` since their Git won't attempt this same guess if they *don't* have one yet.

Comment: So, since in this case, I am passing that information the remote, I was pointing to the wrong one. Got it. 
Great answer! Thank you.